# Android Button Not moving onclick

Tags: java, android

I have an up button which I want to move up onClick but when I click on it it moves way to far and gets to the end of the screen and then shrinks down untill you cant see it. It moves up too much, but why? I only increase it by one unit?

```
final Button upbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.upbutton);

    upbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams mParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)

            upbutton.getLayoutParams();

            mParams.bottomMargin += 1;
            upbutton.setLayoutParams(mParams);

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you're not assigning mParams to your buttons params.

```
mParams = upbutton.getLayoutParams();
```

Comment: instead of upbutton.getLayoutParams();

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be increasing parameters for your `RelativeLayout` then assigning those to your `button`. So the `button` gets  confused. Try looking for a set margin option or something on the actual `button` view.

Comment: Could you elaborate please?

Comment: I apologize, my phone messes with code sometimes. Looking back on it,  it looks pretty good to me. I would suggest saving the value of the current margin and then the new one and making sure the numbers change as expected. Disregard the actual answer I put.